# accessing user Google Drive files from the server

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to offer an application which is to allow access to user's private files through proprietary back end and present them in a custom Web UI. What is the mechanism that allows to bridge the Web-based OAuth to the server side Drive access for each user?

EDIT:
To expand on my brief description, I would like to add that the OAuth authentication to receive the Token Response is to happen through the HTTP interaction and be presented to a user in a Web interface and be of 2-legged nature. But then I thought the Token Response would be passed to a Java server (via HTTP headers), which would process the file to be stored in user's Drive after some processing. What is not clear to me is what APIs are used to manipulate the files in Google Drive from the Java server back-end and how the Token Response is passed to those APIs to facilitate OAuth authentication.

Is this even implementable?

Comment: What did you mean by "mechanism"? Did you mean to ask how it should be implemented, or did you mean to ask how it works?

Comment: if you are doing 2-legged oauth on the client, you can upload the access token to your server. However, your use case is a better fit for 3-legged OAuth at the server.

Comment: I really meant how this should be implemented and also do not understand the need for 3-legged OAuth.